# VB Streamwriter set to ISO-8859-1 but file get UTF8-Without Bom encoding

Tags: .net, vb.net, encoding, text-files, streamwriter

I have a problem i set the streawriter to write ISO-8853-1 but the file gets utf8 encoding. See code below:

when declaring str i set it to iso-8853-1 and when i check the output files encoding i get UTF8-without bom.

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Using str = New StreamWriter("C:\blabla.txt", False, encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"))
        str.Write("23124124AÖ")
        Dim encoding = str.Encoding
        str.Close()
    End Using

    Dim currentEncoding = GetFileEncoding("C:\blabla.txt")
End Sub
    Public Function GetFileEncoding(filePath As String) As Encoding
        Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(filePath, True)
            sr.Read()
            Return sr.CurrentEncoding
        End Using
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Note that the True you have in `StreamReader(filePath, True)` does not mean it will detect the character encoding of your file. It'll only do that if the file have a BOM. Which your file does not have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a reason that you have to pass encodings to the constructors of both readers and writers. Files, in and of themselves, don't **have** encodings.
They're just a collection of bytes.

It's up to *you*, be *selecting* an encoding, to say what interpretation you want to place on those bytes. You opened the [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bc2hwcb(v=vs.110).aspx) without specifying an encoding and so it defaults to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i get what you say. But for example when i open the output text file in either sublime text 3 or notepad++, it says that the encoding of the file is utf8-without bom. Which i feel is a little bit wierd?

Comment: @Rownie - unless there are byte (sequences) in the file that cannot exist in a particular encoding, all you can do given a file is to *guess*. There are in fact some functions available in Windows that provide specific guessing functionality. See [this recent Old New Thing post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/02/23/10595070.aspx) which covers using them (from C++)

Comment: The thing is that this file is supposed to be read into a system which only accepts ISO-8853-1 encoding. But if i understand you correctly they have to specify how to read it, and since the file is written with the correct encoding they should be able to read it correctly? But the file doesn't as you say, have any characters which gets interpereted differently in UTF8 w/o bom and iso-8859-1 so the file itself cant be determined to be either?

Comment: That's the third time you've said 8853 rather than 8859, but I'm almost certain it's not what you [mean](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=16330). If you've written a file in iso-8859-1 encoding and that's the encoding the other program is expecting, all should be well.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, i mean 8859. Now i think i get how it works. Thank you so very much for the help!